# Read webpage - avoid diamond / question mark for non-standard chars

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read a webpage that contains a registered trademark symbol in the content, i.e. ®.  However, when I use quickwatch and look at sb in the below example, I see a diamond with a question mark instead of ®.  The same issue occurs if I serialize sb and display it in another webpage via javascript.  Is this just how this char will appear in my quickwatch window, or am I reading/decoding the page incorrectly?  The code is as follows:

```
    const int bufSize = 4096;
    const int maxBytesToGet = 5000000;
    byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufSize);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            while ((bytesToGet = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) != 0)
            {
                sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, bytesToGet));
                if (sb.Length > maxBytesToGet) break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: trademark fraud bot ? I keep getting those spams. Anyone knows a way to prevent this ? except using an image ?

Comment: i don't understand your comment

Comment: @David, I don't get your comment either, and definitely don't see any reason for a downvote.  This is a pretty straightforward question about encodings.

Comment: No one else keep getting emails that pretend that your trademark is being registered somewhere else ? And of course they offer you to register it 1st ?

Comment: @David, no, no e-mails, and no idea what that has to do with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assuming the response is UTF8.  You need to look at the response headers to see what the encoding actually is.  It's also easier to use a `StreamReader` instead of `Encoding.GetString`.

```
string responseText;

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding))
        {
            responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I ended up using response.CharacterSet instead of response.ContentEncoding

Comment: @Mike your comment was a savior, I got an error using Encoding.GetEncoding(response.ContentEncoding) and when I switched it to Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet) worked like a charm! :D My issue was umlaut and other foreign characters, hopefully this helps the search results. :D

Comment: @TaylorBrown @Mike updated the answer to use `CharacterSet` instead of `ContentEncoding`. Thanks for pointing that out.